# getting folder content C language

Tags: c, macos

How can i get the paths of a folder and its content. Say i have folder named MyFolder as

/tmp/MyFolder/ where it has subfolders SubFolder1, SubFolder2... and some files

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Do you want to obtain a directory / file listing of /tmp/MyFolder or 'absolutize' a path within it?

Comment: I know your question is tagged c but in obj-c you use NSDirectoryEnumerator.  There is probably a similar function in the CoreFoundation framework.

Comment: Are you looking for opendir/readdir or did I misread the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [`opendir()`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/opendir.3.html) family functions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Even though i am using some other related functions under the same framework...

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way than {open,read,close}dir() is Linux' getdirentries() function. See getdirentries(3) for details.

Comment: I think that is linux centric, the OP is asking about Mac OS/X.

Comment: getdirentries is present on BSDs and MacOS/X

Answer (score 0):

Use dirent and dir structures. You can use opendir(), readdir() etc for manipulation.

readdir() will give one name at a time and you can keep calling it iteratively.